# Shortcut to move to a branch ignoring local changes

Tags: git

I frequently need to checkout a branch and pull the origin HEAD (ignoring local made to the branch).
This happens because my colleagues force-push to a branch often and I need to test their changes.
I usually use:

```
git checkout amazing_feature_branch
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/amazing_feature_branch
```

I think I could also use:

```
git checkout amazing_feature_branch
git fetch origin
git reset --hard @{u}
```

Is there an easier way? Or shall I simply create an alias for this?

Comment: "Easier" tends to be in the eye (or keyboard) of the beholder (or typist), but I'd go with the alias or just `git checkout origin/foo` after `git fetch`. The latter puts you in detached HEAD mode on the specified commit.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Have you made local changes to amazing_feature_branch and you want to throw them out?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bring a local branch up to date with a rebased remote, use `git pull --rebase`.

If you have made any actual local changes they will be preserved and rebased on top of the remote branch.

For example, let's say you committed 1, 2, 3 locally on top of an old version of the remote branch, but it's been rebased.

```
origin
A - Q - C - X - E - Z [feature]

local
A - B - C - D - E - F [origin/feature]
                     \
                      1 - 2 - 3 [feature]
```

If you `git checkout feature; git pull --rebase` it will rewrite your local changes on top of the rebased branch.

```
origin
A - Q - C - X - E - Z [feature]

local
A - Q - C - X - E - Z [origin/feature]
                     \
                      1 - 2 - 3 [feature]
```

If you want to test the rebased remote without your local changes, checkout `origin/feature`.

You can configure this to be the default by setting `pull.rebase` to `merges` (this will preserve merges while rebasing). I recommend this. It is safe, it handles upstream rebasing, and it avoids cluttering up the history with inconsequential update merges.